# How is the converting from one form to another specified in Android Studio with Kotlin tool

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm learning Android developer by using Kotlin. I have finished the tutorials for Kotlin, but when I started Android Studio one question arised.

For example if we want to set the button OnClickListener() and the taking the input why do we first convert the input to String and then to the Int?

```
buttonid.setOnClickListener {
   var x:Int = numid.text.toString().toInt()

}
```

Why should it be in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text property of a `Button` in Kotlin is of type `CharSequence`.

[image]

There is no conversion method from `CharSequence` to `Int`, but there is one for conversion from `CharSequence` to `String` as well as one for conversion from `String` to `Int`. So we concatenate the two - et voilà

Comment: That one explains a lot. Thanks, sir, I made your answer as accepted.